# Подсчет результатов теста полученных из json в форме

Tags: php, html, массивы, json, get

Помогите завершить пожалуйста.
Данный код применяется для декодирования json файла из директории и создание из него некого теста. Мне нужно чтобы при отправке формы, введенные значения записывались в массив и в конце выводился результат сколько правильных ответов, сколько не правильных.
 Я, вероятно, не правильный формат форме задал, может проще реализовать с помощью маркеров выбора, и одной кнопкой результаты отправлять?

```
<?php
$test_dir = "./tests/test";
$test_id = $test_dir.$_GET["id"].".json";
$json_file = file_get_contents($test_id);
$json_array = json_decode($json_file, true);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="list.php">Список тестов</a></li>
        <li><a href="admin.php">Загрузить тест</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<?php
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($json_array);

$result=[];
?>

    <form action="" method="GET" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <h1><?php echo $json_array[0]['question'] ?></h1>
        <h2>Варианты ответов:</h2>
        <?php foreach ($json_array[0]['answers'] as $values) { ?>
        <p> <?php echo $values; ?> </p>
        <?php } ?>
        Напишите номер ответа: <input type="text" name="question1" value=" "><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Ответить">
    </form>

    <form action="" method="GET" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <h1><?php echo $json_array[1]['question'] ?></h1>
        <h2>Варианты ответов:</h2>
        <?php foreach ($json_array[1]['answers'] as $values) { ?>
        <p> <?php echo $values; ?> </p>
        <?php } ?>
        Напишите номер ответа: <input type="text" name="question2" value=" "><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Ответить">
    </form>    

    <form action="" method="GET" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <h1><?php echo $json_array[2]['question'] ?></h1>
        <h2>Варианты ответов:</h2>
        <?php foreach ($json_array[2]['answers'] as $values) { ?>
        <p> <?php echo $values; ?> </p>
        <?php } ?>
        Напишите номер ответа: <input type="text" name="question3" value=" "><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Ответить">
    </form>

<?php
  $answer1 = $_GET['question1'];
  $answer2 = $_GET['question2'];
  $answer3 = $_GET['question3'];
  $result = [$answer1, $answer2, $answer3];

  echo "<pre>";
var_dump($result);

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Ниже структура json теста.

```
  [{
    "question": "Столица России?",
    "answers": 
        {
        "1": "1. Париж",
        "2": "2. Вашингтон",
        "3": "3. Питер",
        "4": "4. Москва"
        },
    "correct_answer": "4"
},
{
    "question": "Какой сейчас год?",
    "answers": 
        {
        "1": "1. 2025",
        "2": "2. 1991",
        "3": "3. 2017",
        "4": "4. 2013"
        },
    "correct_answer": "3"
},
{
    "question": "Сколько дней в январе?",
    "answers": 
        {
        "1": "1. 31",
        "2": "2. 29",
        "3": "3. 30",
        "4": "4. 28"
        },
    "correct_answer": "1"
}]
```

Comment: зачем вам сабмиты после каждого вопроса?

Comment: @teran наверное чтобы в БД записывать результат или в другое хранилище

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас каждый вопрос это форма. При нажатии на кнопку ответить происходит отпавка формы и вызов скрипта соответсвенно. И каждый раз вызыватся "новая копия" скрипта которая нечего не знает о всех прошлых вызовах. Для того чтобы запонить ответы пользователей данные ответов нужно записывать в сессию, базу или файл.
Например используем сессии. В самом начале файла первой строкой после

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['question1'])) {
    $_SESSION['answers'][1] = $_GET['question1'];
}
if (isset($_GET['question2'])) {
    $_SESSION['answers'][2] = $_GET['question1'];
}
if (isset($_GET['question3'])) {
    $_SESSION['answers'][3] = $_GET['question3'];
}

var_dump($_SESSION['answers']);
?>
```

Это для примера конечно получать ответы нужно в цикле по количеству вопросов в json файле. В конечно итоге у вас в $_SESSION['answers'] будет массив ответов пользователя который нужно проверить на правельность и вывести колличество.

Comment: Спасибо, за развернутый ответ, но мне достаточно сложно это понять. Я, наверное, далек от понимания этого и нужна доп. Информация по этому материалу, где почмотреть, почитать, чтобы доступно было, не подскажете?

Comment: По сессиям http://php.net/manual/ru/session.examples.basic.php

Comment: Вообще для начала http://php.net/manual/ru/tutorial.php